# interrupt switch (PIC)

Tags: switch-statement, interrupt, pic

```
#define SW1 RB5
int IOFlag = 2; //while in out

void SW(){
    if(!RB5)
        __delay_ms(50);
        while(!RB5);
            __delay_ms(50);
        IOFlag++;
}

void main(){
    SW();
    while(IOFlag % 2 != 0){
        SW();
        //some routines..
    }
}
```

I used pic16f73, RB5 input use for switch. 
When some of the routine is running, switch is not operating properly.
It is possible if you use the interrupt. However I don't know how to use it properly.

Comment: Many people starting with PIC programming stumble over the watchdog being active and look for errors in their code, not noticing the fact that the active watchdog resets the program every 50ms (or so). You can turn watchdog off in that download tool (checkbox).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between polling and interrupts.

With polling (what you appear to be doing), you periodically check the state of some "thing" and act on it.

With interrupts, the "thing" happening causes your main thread of execution to be suspended, and an interrupt service routine (ISR) run.

Polling has the disadvantage of potentially long latency, the time between the thing happening and you finding out about it. In fact, you can even *lose* events if the thing is a momentary switch for example - you switch it on then off then, when the code checks for it, it's off.

Now you *can* still use polling if you wish, provided you understand these implications. Sometimes the easiest solution is to poll more often.

For example, if one of your `//some routines..` jobs is a long running loop, you can poll from within there:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numThings; i++) {
    doSomethingQuickWitn (thing[i]);
    SW(); // Poll here as well
}
// Rather than here.
```

---

However, for _minimal latency, using interrupts is usually better and is *reasonably* simple once you wrap your head around the concept.

Your ISR (which will run on the given event, interrupting the main thread of execution) simply has to store the fact that the event has happened and communicate that to your main thread somehow.

For situations where you don't care how many times the event has happened, a flag will do the job. Your ISR simply sets the flag and your main thread of execution checks it periodically to see if it's been set, then clears it (with interrupts disabled so as to avoid race conditions). That would be something like (pseudo-code):

```
global val switchHit = false;

main:
    interrupt (7, intFn)       // call intfn() on interrupt 7
    while true:
        disableInts()          // disallow interrupts for a short while
        if switchHit:
            handleSwitch()     // switch was hit, do something (quickly)
            switchHit = false  // mark as not hit
        enableInts()           // and re-allow interrupts

        doLotsOfOtherStuff()

intfn:
    switchHit = true           // notify main
```

Note that I'm not worry about race conditions within the ISR, interrupts are *generally* disabled automatically there.

More complicated information transfer may involve a count rather than a flag, or even a message queue of some sort, flowing from the ISR to the main thread of execution.

Comment: Depending on triggering mode of the interrupt sensitive input (edge or level triggered), you can also run into the problems you described for polling while using interrupts. Also, once you use interrupts, your code becomes nondeterministic. This is why some (e.g. Military, Medicine) resort to polling and proving that their loops and the longest paths of code are within the boundary they need for their "real time".

Comment: but i cant understand your code. that is pseudo code?

Comment: @최인혁, yes, it's pseudo-code, I'll make that clear in the answer. I thought that would be preferable to illustrate the point since assembler code would almost certainly be larger and potentially likely to get in the way of understanding.

Comment: yes i think so too. thank you. try again, try again, try again, hahaha